# Counting the vowels in each name, and displaying separately

Tags: java, arrays, count, names

How I would get this code to count the vowels in each word rather than adding all the vowels up and displaying these. The code I have written:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Arrays;
String[] names = new String[12];
int i;
int j;
j=0;
int vowelCount;
vowelCount=0;
char ch;
names[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name");
names[1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name");
names[2] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name");
names[3] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name");
names[4] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name");
names[5] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name");
names[6] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name");
names[7] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name");
names[8] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name");
names[9] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name");
names[10] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name");
names[11] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a name");

Arrays.sort(names);

System.out.println("Name" + "        " + "Characters" + "    " + "Vowels");

for (i=0; i<12; i++)

 {
   for(j=0; j<names[i].length(); j++)
    {
      ch=names[i].charAt(j);

      if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'i' || 
      ch == 'I' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U')
        vowelCount ++;
    }


System.out.println(names[i] + "       " +names[i].length() + "             " + vowelCount);

 }
```

I need the code to accept a user inputted name (which it does), sort the names alphabetically (which it does), count the characters in each name (which it does), and then display the vowels in each name.

Comment: You could add all the vowels in an array or a list and then compare each character in the name to each character stored in the vowels array. ArrayList has the method `contains()` which you could use

Comment: Just reset `vowelCount` back to `0` at the beginning of your outer loop, and it will represent the vowels found in that each, instead of a running total.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to write code for processing lowercase and uppercase letters. You could e.g. only store lowercase vowels in an ArrayList and then transform a name to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a collection of some sort, most likely an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). As you count the number of vowels, add them to the list.

```
//declare collection here
for(j=0; j<names[i].length(); j++)
{
  ch=names[i].charAt(j);

  if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'i' || 
     ch == 'I' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U')
        vowelCount ++;
        //add ch character to collection
    }
System.out.println(names[i] + "       " +names[i].length() + "             " + vowelCount);
//print vowels in collection
```

[Example use of ArrayList](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)

---

Just for extra information if you are interested, there are a number of collections you can use depending on whether you need a value/key pair, if you can allow duplicate entries, and if you want a certain order. Additionally, they perform differently depending on how you are using them.

[Comparison Chart between different Collection](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/comparison-chart-between-different-collection/)

[image: Collection comparison chart]